# jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy received function: [Function getTemplates]

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I have a function in module called handlelistOfTemplates which calls actions defined in another file. I want to test when handlelistOfTemplates is called the function in actions file is called with correct parameters.

My container component :

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

import * as getData from '../../services/DataService';

class Container extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props) 
        this.props.actions.getTemplates(1);
        this.state = {
            value: 1
        }

    }

    handlelistOfTemplates = (template, index, value) => {
        this.props.selectedTemplate(template);
        this.setState({ value });
        this.props.actions.getTemplates(template);
    };

    componentDidMount() {
    }

    render() {
        return(

                <ListOfTemplates listOfTemplates={this.props.listOfTemplates} value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handlelistOfTemplates}/>
            );
    }
}
function mapStateToProps({state}) {
    return {
        listOfTemplates: state.listOfTemplates
    }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(getData, dispatch)
    };
   }
module.exports = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Container);
```

And my test :

```
import React from 'react';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import expect from 'expect';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import { createMockStore, createMockDispatch } from 'redux-test-utils';

import Container from './Container';
const shallowWithStore = (component, store) => {
    const context = {
        store,
        muiTheme: getMuiTheme(),
    };

    const childContextTypes = {
        muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }
    return shallow(component, { context, childContextTypes });
};
let store;
const loadComponent = (testState) => {

    const props = {
        actions: {
            getTemplates: () => {return Promise.resolve()}
        }
    }
    store = createMockStore(testState)
    return shallowWithStore(<Container {...props}/>, store);
}

const getFakeState = () => {
    return {
        listOfTemplates: [],

    };
}

describe('Container', () => {
    let testState, component;


    describe("when Appeal template is selected from select template dropdown", () => {
        beforeAll(() => {
            testState = getFakeState();
            component = loadComponent(testState);

        });

        fit('should update the content in editor', (done) => {
            component.dive().find('ListOfTemplates').props().onChange('Appeal', 1, 2);
            component.update();
            done();
            expect(component.dive().state().value).toEqual(2) // error value still is at 1
expect(component.instance().props.actions.getTemplates).toHaveBeenCalled();

        });
    });
});
```

When I run the above test I get the following error.

```
expect(jest.fn())[.not].toHaveBeenCalled()

    jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
    Received:
      function: [Function getTemplates]
```

Is there something else I should be running to get this to work ?may be my mock is not correct.

even i tried doing this : 
jest.spyon(component.instance().props.actions, 'getTemplates'); before expect the error remains same.

Also, when i checking the component's local state has been modified or not. I'm not getting the updated state. 
 when i call `component.dive().find('ListOfTemplates').props().onChange('Appeal', 1, 2);`

the `component.dive().state().value` should become 2 but it is 1 instead.

Could you please help me where i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You should pass a Mock function `getTemplate` to your component, otherwise `jest` won't be able to check whether it was called or not.

You can do that like this: (notice `jest.fn()` )

```
 const props = {
        actions: {
            getTemplates: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve())
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I'l still getting error with your suggested change. Error  --- 

TypeError: received.getMockName is not a function

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/containers/Container.spec.js:183:169)
          at new Promise (<anonymous>)
          at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

Comment: What's is `getTemplateContent` in your tests?